# Class not dispatching

Tags: php, class, dispatcher, bootstrapping

I'm using xampp localhost php 5.4.31 for my projects. My particular project script runs as expected on my localhost but, once uploaded to the server (running Apache, Php 5.3.3) I've come across a strange situation whereby the script doesn't go beyond a certain point in my code and doesn’t report any error messages!

I have an index.php file which loads all my necessary classes (inc ‘bootstrap.class.php’ which is in my “apps” folder!) then dispatches the bootstrap class. This runs fine up until this line:
`$dispatch = new $controllerName();` which it will not go beyond! WHY?

```
$controllerFile =  CONTROLLERS . $controllerName . '.class.php'; 

require_once($controllerFile);

if(class_exists($controllerName)) echo "YES <br />\n";

try{
    echo "[A: '$controllerName'] <br />";

        $dispatch = new $controllerName();

    print_r($dispatch);

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

### localhost will display:

```
YES
[A: 'indexcontroller']
indexcontroller Object (....blah blah blah.....
```

---

### server displays:

```
YES
[A: 'indexcontroller']
```

---

Any thoughts - any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Check your `indexcontroller` file for syntax errors on the server, it may be that you're using PHP version-specific syntax that gives a fatal error with the version of PHP you're running on the server, often a problem if you're running different PHP versions between server and localhost

Comment: It does raise the question of why you're not running the same version of PHP on your development environment and on your server, which is unforgivable in this age of virtual machines

Comment: Although I agree with your comment "why you're not running the same version of Php on your development environment", I didn't check the server version until this problem occurred, never expecting such an error - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is bug for php 5.3.3 please upgrade server php4
Related link : https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60701

Comment: Pointing to an arbitrary bug without any evidence to suggest that this could be the cause isn't particularly useful; what makes you think OP's indexcontroller has a __toString() method that references $this, and that they're getting a segfault?

Comment: I provide a link. Php 5.3.x has a bug about return an object and __toString method.

Comment: I read the link.... I just don't know how you know that OP's indexcontroller has a __toString() method that references $this, and that they're getting a segfault? They don't mention this anywhere in their question.... there's plenty of other bugs in PHP 5.3.3, so what makes you so sure that their problem is caused by this specific bug? The same symptons could be displayed if their indexcontroller contained a line like `$x = $this->getMyArray()[1];` (array dereferencing is valid in PHP 5.4 but would give a fatal error in PHP 5.3)

Comment: Yes you are right, i don't know exist or not _toString method. And i found new bug for dump object :
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50027#1289900303